# How to convert spherical to cartesian coordinates in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I tried to convert spherical to cartesian coordinates in postgresql.

Illustrations:

- Input: elevation, azimuth
- Output: x, y, z

Sample data

```
hour    Elevation   Azimuth x   y   z
06:29:00    -0.833  67.72   0.379094033 0.9252439455    -0.0145380682
07:00:00    6.28    68.75   0.3602640625    0.9264147202    0.1093872546
08:00:00    20.15   69.78   0.3244723425    0.880938168 0.3444787991
09:00:00    34.06   69.39   0.2916199874    0.7754290366    0.5600603468
```

Any queries or functions are there to convert?

I tried to create a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_spr2cart(point_a geometry, point_b geometry)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(
  Cos(a1) * Cos(b1),
  Cos (a1) * sin (b1),
  sin(a1)), ST_SRID($1))
FROM (SELECT
  ST_m($1) AS a1, 
  ST_m($2) AS b1
) AS f$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Function created but when I execute it, there is an error.

Comment: i added whatever i tried......

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_spr2cart(point_a float, point_b float)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$SELECT ST_MakePoint(
  Cos(a * pi() / 180) * Cos(b * pi() / 180),
  Cos(a * pi() / 180) * sin(b * pi() / 180),
  sin(a * pi() / 180))
FROM (SELECT
 $1 AS a, 
 $2 AS b
) AS f$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

select st_astext(ST_spr2cart (elevation , azimuth)) from tablename;
```